# Join 2 arched curves

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]
Been working in Blender for 4 yrs coming from 10+yrs of previous 3dsmax experience. And every now and then I stumble upon the simplest shortcomings that seem logical to have been implemented, but for some reason they are not. One of these is curve operations. In the case of straight Poly lines this method works well, but with arched curves it is impossible. Maybe you know some workaround? Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mirror modifier allows merging vertices, so put the origin on the right vertex (select it > cursor to selected > origin to 3D cursor) and mirror the curve. And you have addons as well to automate the process in brackets.